# Git can't add file

Tags: git, github

I have this file: `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` and when I try `git add Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` I get the following error: `sh: syntax error near unexpected token`('` is there a workaround...or I need to rename the file...

Comment: You're parsing two values to `git add`: `Default` and `(OSX).sublime-keymap`. That's not what you want probably :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two related problems with your use of the command line, neither of which is specific to Git:

- Parentheses need to be escaped. Your command line shell is actually an interpreter, and parentheses are significant to it.
- Spaces need to be escaped. Spaces separate commands and arguments. Assuming you've escape the parentheses, you're now passing two files to `git add`, one called "Default" and one called "(OSX).sublime-keymap".

You need to either use quotes around the whole filename, or escape the parentheses and spaces with backslashes:

```
git add "Default (OSX).sublime-keymap"
```

or

```
git add Default\ \(OSX\).submlime-keymap
```

Note that your shell may support tab-completion. Try typing `git add Def` and hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> a few times, and your shell may auto-complete the filename for you, correctly escaping the spaces and parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Either rename your file or escape the parentheses and whitespace:

```
git add Default\ \(OSX\).sublime-keymap
```